# How to add a custom field to a post created programmatically?

Tags: custom-field

How to add a custom field to my post when created programmatically?

I am trying to create a post programmatically, and store a value in a column created directly from PhpMyAdmin.

[image]

Here is how I am creating the post:

```
$post_title = $post->title->rendered;
$post_content = $post->content->rendered;

$post_check = get_page_by_title($post_title);
$post = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_title' => $post_title,
    'post_content' => $post_content,
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'post_author' => 1,
    'post_slug' => $post_title,
    'post_imported_id' => 3

);
$post_id = wp_insert_post($post);
if ($post_id) {
    add_post_meta( $post_id, 'post_imported_id', 3 );
}
```

The post is created and all default fields are well saved too.

The problem is that my "post_imported_id" is not taken in consideration.

Answer (score 2):

You have created a custom field by altering the post table in the database. Custom fields in WordPress API are considered meta fields; such fields are stored in `wp_postmeta` table and that is the table used by functions like `add_post_meta()` and the rest of the functions and methods related with post custom/meta fields.

You can check how to work with meta/custom fields in the [MetaData section of plugin developer handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/metadata/).

PD: Altering core database tables is considered a very bad practice.

Answer (score 1):

When you use the `add_post_meta()` method, the custom post meta value will be stored automatically in the `wp_postmeta` table which has four columns: ID, post_id, meta_key and meta_value. So, in my opinion there is no reason for you to create an extra column manually and store your custom value there.

Later on, if you want to get the custom meta value for your post, just use the `get_post_meta()` method.

I hope this helps.